# How can I add a translation template-tag inside another template-tag in Django?

Tags: django, templates, tags, translation

This is my template code:

```py
{{ can_edit|yesno:'Allow edit,View Only' }}
```

But I want to translate it automatically from my translation strings, so I did this:

```py
{{ can_edit|yesno:'{% trans "option_allow_edit" %},{% trans "option_allow_edit" %}' }}
```

But it doesn't work, because it escapes the `{% trans %}` tags.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

**You can use the `_()` syntax.**

Here is an example from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#string-literals-passed-to-tags-and-filters):

```py
{% some_tag _("Page not found") value|yesno:_("yes,no") %
```

---

So in your case you can do this:

```py
{{ can_edit|yesno:_('Allow edit,View Only') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the [blocktrans template tag.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag)

```
{% blocktrans with editable=can_edit|yesno:'Allow edit,View Only' %}
    {{ editable }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```